# specify the sound file in request in twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-programmable-chat

I am started to learn twilio and currently using it on the local server to make some basic call practices. For the testing purposes i have used twilio code.

```
$call = $twilio->calls
               ->create("+123",
                        "+123",
                        array("url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml")
               );
```

Problem i am getting is is there any other way i have to redirect the `url` parameter to local? How can i specify the `Say` and `Play` parameters in the `url` array.

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/02/emophone-how-to-build-a-twilio-powered-ivr-using-php-and-ngrok.html

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Yes, you can direct the call to a URL on your local machine. I recommend you use a tool called [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) for this. I like using [ngrok for a bunch of reasons](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/6-awesome-reasons-to-use-ngrok-when-testing-webhooks.html), but the most important is that it opens up a tunnel from the public internet to a port on your machine. It gives you a public URL for that, which you can use in your Twilio calls.